# Is there a way to enqueue asynchronous I/O operations?

Tags: java, asynchronous, queue, nio

Specifically, the behaviour I am looking for is this: 
Read operations happen concurrently, and will execute once all pending write operations are finished.
Write operations always wait until all other read/write operations are completed.
Close operations always wait until all other read/write operations are completed.
In other words, these operations should be enqueued.

The official documentation for NIO FileLocks does not specify this behaviour. Infact it states that:

> File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They
>   are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads
>   within the same virtual machine.

I have played with idea of manually enqueing all the requests and calling get() on all outstanding Futures before submitting a new I/O request
but I have no idea if this is even a good idea.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

EDIT: Thanks to fge's insights I have managed to find a basic solution to my problem:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class ChannelAccessFactory {

    public static final ExecutorService IO_THREADS = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    private final Path file;
    private final ReadWriteLock lock;

    public ChannelAccessFactory (Path file){
        this.file = file;
        this.lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    }

    public ReadWriteLock getLock(){
        return lock;
    }

    public ChannelAccess newAccess() throws Exception{
        return new ChannelAccess(file, lock);
    }

}
```

Wrapped Channel class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;

public class ChannelAccess implements AutoCloseable{

    private final ReadWriteLock lock;
    private final AsynchronousFileChannel channel;

    protected ChannelAccess (Path file, ReadWriteLock lock) throws Exception{
        this.lock = lock;
        this.channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(file, StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
    }

    public Future<Integer> read(final ByteBuffer buffer, final long position){
        return ChannelAccessFactory.IO_THREADS.submit(new Callable<Integer>(){
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
                lock.readLock().lock();
                try{
                    return channel.read(buffer, position).get();
                }
                finally {
                    lock.readLock().unlock();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Future<Integer> write(final ByteBuffer buffer, final long position){
        return ChannelAccessFactory.IO_THREADS.submit(new Callable<Integer>(){
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
                lock.writeLock().lock();
                try{
                    return channel.write(buffer, position).get();
                }
                finally {
                    lock.writeLock().unlock();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public long size() throws Exception{
        lock.readLock().lock();
        try{
            return channel.size();
        }
        finally{
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        try{
            channel.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){}
        finally{
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). It allows many concurrent readers but only one writer.

It is not a "pure" NIO solution but it is a primitive which behaves the way you want.

**Beware**: use locks like this to avoid deadlocks:

```
rwlock.readLock().lock();
try {
    // do stuff
} finally {
    rwlock.readLock().unlock();
}
```

Comment: OK, I understand how this can be used for specific references to a single object. But how can I use this to target the same channel, which may very well exist as a set of multiple distinct references/objects?

Comment: Do you mean you can have several channels associated to the same file?

Comment: What I want is a lock to the same physical file on my HDD, not an object in the JVM.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot "really" have that: file locks are cooperative. Another process can write to the same file without acquiring a lock at all. If you mean to lock a file so that only one _process_ can do it, Java cannot guarantee that as far as I know.

Comment: Then, if you really want to do an "inter thread lock" of the file, you can always wrap the `Path` (or `File` if you are still stuck with that) in an rwlock.

Comment: It would be enough if one instance of the same java application would recognize equivalent channels (i.e. channels for equivalent file paths) as identical, I guess. What would I have to do to realize that, in regard to locks?

Comment: Is this also related to your other question to which I recommended using LoadingCache? If yes, I have an idea but would need to know a little more.

Comment: Yes. I have a set of around 60-100k files (or variant size), all of which may be accessed at any time. In case a write interferes with a read, all I want is for the write (and any subsqeuent reads/writes) to wait for the current I/O operation to finish. Since I cannot reasonably maintain a connection to every single file (too many), channels have to be closed as soon as they are no longer in use. Identity checks are not useful here. I can use equality checks to cache path values, but this is not an elegant solution at all, because this way, I rely on GC to close channels which may kill the OS.

Comment: My idea was since FileChannel was abstract, you could make a class extending it and wrapping all read/write operations in an rwlock. This way, when one attempts to read or write, they would have to acquire the lock before they actually read/write to the underlying channel.

Comment: Is there any guarantee for that to work with AsynchronousChannel implementations that return Futures? Or will I have to rely on completion handling to make sure that locks are not unlocked prematurey?

Comment: That is a good question, actually. I don't use AsynchronousChannels so I cannot answer, but you have to remember that locks/unlocks are per thread, so if the completion handler spawns another thread you had better not do that.

Comment: It could, yes, however you could make the inner class' instance variables final